# Is it possible to edit an Office document stored in the cloud using the Office 365 API?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, office365, office365-apps, office365api

Is it possible to integrate our asp.net (vb.net) web site with Office 365 so our customers with Office 365 subscriptions can edit documents stored on our servers with the online office 365 editors?

Our site already does this with Google Docs editor and Zoho so now we want to add Office

I have tried the Office 365 starter project and the single tenant and multiple tenant projects with Visual Studio 2013. However, when I opened up my asp.net web site in visual studio 2013, the menu item `Add-> Connected service` is missing. But, it is present for an asp.net MVC project.

Comment: Please see this post on [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Hi Rick, I already read that before I posted. Please help me by letting me know where I can improve on my post. I just joined Stackoverflow and any tips would help. Thanks for responding.

Comment: I've edited your question.  FYI, it took me about 10 minutes to understand what your question was.  I'm still not entirely sure how the last paragraph relates to the question.  Try to keep your questions more to the point.  Paragraphs with more than 3 lines tend not to get read.  Your question is a bit broad and I think might actually be 2 questions: Is this possible and why doesn't this menu item show up.  Very narrow specific questions get answered, broad ones don't.  Hope this helps you get an answer.  I'm afraid I don't know the answer.

Comment: Thank you, really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to provide Office Online as a way to edit documents that are stored on your server. Please check out the Office 365 Cloud Storage Partner Program http://dev.office.com/programs/officecloudstorage (specifically the section on Office Online Integration)

Comment: Thank you. I will try it out.

Comment: I have applied for the "Office 365 - Cloud Storage Partner Program Registration" more than 10 days back and haven't got any response yet. I didn't even get any confirmation email of my form submission. is there a phone number of contact email where I can enquire about my registration?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it.Try to install the files for Microsoft.Office365.OutlookServices.dll in your application the "Add-> Connected service" will shown for the application.Then follow the following link 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn776319(v=exchg.150).aspx