# Can you edit a microsoft document stored on S3 with office 365 (2021)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, microsoft-graph-api, office365

is it possible to use the Office 365 API (which I believe is now called Microsoft Graph) to do the following:

1. grant access to or download and upload an office doc to temporary Microsoft Storage
2. let a licensed user edit the doc in Office 365
3. upon save, download or programattically update the S3 file?

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32259860/is-it-possible-to-edit-an-office-document-stored-in-the-cloud-using-the-office-3), but it's from 2015 and the link is dead.

Thanks for any help,
Kevin

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to handle the first two steps without a problem. Assuming they have the proper licensing, uploading a document to OneDrive and retrieving the resulting metadata will provide a URI you can use to open it in the correct Office application.

The challenge will be determining when they are done editing a document. The best option I can think of would be to use a [delta query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-delta?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) to determine if the file has changed. There are however some potential conditions (i.e. they could save a doc but still have the editor open) so you may want a 4th step where the user "checks in" the finished document.

Answer (score 0):

The File Fabric from Storage Made Easy [facilitates editing](https://eu.storagemadeeasy.com/microsoft-office-online/) of Amazon S3 documents, including the collaborative mode, with Microsoft Office Online.